# Limit of variance of $n$ sided cube

Tags: probability, limits

Let $C$ be the random number of a $n$-sided cube, where all sides have the same probability.

I have to find out the limit of
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} V(C/n),$$ where $V$ is variance.

First of all I don't know what is $V(C/n)$. I don't know how to imagine that.

Comment: Presumably $C$ is a random integer from $1$ to $n$, so $\frac Cn$ ranges from $\frac 1n$ to $\frac nn=1$.  You are asked to find the variance of this distribution as a function of $n$ and take the indicated limit.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) may help.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "$n$-sided cube," as every cube has exactly six sides. Perhaps you mean an $n$-sided die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you mean an $n$-sided die. You know that

$$
V(C/n) = \mathbb{E}(C^2/n^2) - \mathbb{E}(C/n)^2.
$$

The expectation of $C$ is $\frac{1}{n}(1+\cdots+n) = \frac{n+1}{2}$ and so the second term is

$$
\mathbb{E}(C/n)^2 = \Big(\frac{n+1}{2n}\Big)^2 \to \frac{1}{4}
$$ as $n\to\infty$.

The values of $C^2$ are $1,4,9,\dots,n^2$ with equal probability so the expectation of this random variable is the $1/n$ times the sum of the first $n$ squared integers, i.e.

$$
\frac{1}{n}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$

So,

$$
\mathbb{E}(C^2/n^2) = \frac{1}{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\to \frac{1}{3}.
$$

This means your answer should be $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: i dont get this step. can you explain it in more detail? : so the expectation of this random variable is the $1/n$ times the sum of the first $n$ squared integers, i.e.

$$
\frac{1}{n}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$

Comment: Sure: the second fraction is a famous expression for the sum of the first $n$ squares. The first $\frac{1}{n}$ tells you to take the average of this sum. Together they give you the expectation.